# vSphere 5.5 Can't tick "connect" for VM Networks

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, esxi, vsphere

We are using vSphere 5.5.0.
Using the vSphere Web Client, when I create a new VM or add a new NIC to an old VM, if I tick "connect" for the VM nentwork, the task is completed without error.
But when I reopen the settings window the checkmark is missing again and the VM is not connected to the Network.

[image]

The problem occours for every user, every VM on every host.

Those VMs are all Hardware Version 10 and can only be modified via the vSphere Web Client.
I created a new VM with Hardware Version 8, which can be edited with the vSphere Desktop Client.
I can connect this VM to the network using the Desktop Client, but can't do it via the Web Client.

It looks like a bug to me, but we have done no upgrades recently.